# Running a "supported" query on Youtube analytics v2 API returns "unsupported" response

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics, kingswaysoft

I am using kingswaysoft productivy pack's REST component to create a connection to youtube analytics API and fetch video_id data from it. The query I am trying to run is listed [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports#video-reports).

I want the video (video_id) dimension from Youtube's "Top videos by youtube product" endpoint.

Despite stating that the query is supported, when I try to run it I get this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (Error Type / Reason: Bad Request, Detailed Message: {
> "error": {
> "code": 400,
> "message": "The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v2/available_reports for a list of supported queries.",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v2/available_reports for a list of supported queries.",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "badRequest"
> }
> ]
> }
> }

Could this be a location based problem?